# Why Rest API response is giving question mark "?????" for the Arabic language in Azure Build Report

Tags: azure, rest, rest-assured

In Rest Assured Automation, Expectation is to validate Arabic text in Response. In local system, While hitting the API getting the Response in Arabic format. But the same script is not running in the Azure Pipeline because getting the API response in the symbol like this "??????" format

Comment: hmm perhaps it needs the right `Accept-Language` header? Can you see the `Content-Type` header of the response?

Comment: Say you have Unicode text, like a java String. Then the production of bytes requires a specific encoding (charset) for those bytes, even if it is UTF-8 (a Unicode format). In your case the used encoding (probably the default, Latin-1, ISO-8859-1) cannot represent Arabic script in bytes, and generates question marks instead.

Comment: @jspcal I have checked the header and value is "application/json;charset=UTF-8"